# Is the a best way to integrate Liquibase within your gitlab-ci pipelines?

Tags: liquibase, gitlab-ci

I am tying to find a best way or documentation that can assist me with moving our liquibase deployments from Jenkins to Gitlab-C.

If you have done this before please assist I am really struggling to find help